# Fb.Logout function doesn't log user out

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've created a one page application where the idea is to log user in with facebook, get the basic details and log him out of facebook. It's kind of a promotional feature so once one user logs out the other user is asked to log into his facebook account.

This works like this, when a user clicks on Facebook login button on the website, I use FB.login and FB.api methods to get user data. That works fine. Now, when the user fills in some extra fields, and click submit and logout button, I'm storing user data via AJAX call and then calling FB.logout.

Now, this works perfectly on local machine but on the server, as soon as FB.logout method is called, it gives the following error:

**

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.facebook.com/home.php does
>   not permit framing.

**

This is the code I'm using:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: APP_ID,
        channelUrl: apiUrl + 'channel',
        oauth: true,
        frictionlessRequests: true,
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
    });
```

The Fb.login and Fb.logout is as it should be and Fb.login is working. Just the FB.logout that gives the error on server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a problem of using multiple URLs in the websites section in the app settings. The facebook support team also suggested to use the new 'Test Apps' for staging and dev purposes.